# surveys about technologies, tools and methods in automated testing

Tags: automated-testing

Which technologies, tools and methods in automated testing are considered current? Which are considered to be available for heavy production use in a year?

Are there surveys about these things?

Please provide links to surveys as well as links that discuss issues in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I <s>like</s> feel forced to read [Gartner's "Magic Quadrant for Software Test Automation"](https://www.gartner.com/doc/3512920/magic-quadrant-software-test-automation) and [Forrester's "Modern Application Functional Test Automation Tools"](https://www.forrester.com/report/The+Forrester+Wave+Modern+Application+Functional+Test+Automation+Tools+Q4+2016/-/E-RES123866) to somewhat "keep up" (don't purchase, just Google them…). You can also use [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/) or [Stack Overflow Insights](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/) (especially [Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends)) to analyze/compare specific technologies, tools, and methods. Moreover, you often find interesting surveys on corresponding sites such as [StickyMinds](https://stickyminds.com/) or [Software Testing Magazine](http://softwaretestingmagazine.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The two surveys seem interesting, albeit a bit short and only focused on commercial solutions.

How do you use trends and insights to find trends? I want to find keywords or tags out that are trending, these two seem two require me to know tags/keywords in advance...

Comment: @mike Indeed, Gartner and Forrester focus on commercial tool vendors, but they also include open source solutions. To find keywords: Google Trends, for instance, shows [related searches](https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4355000?hl=en). You can also start with an up-to-date article (e.g. ["6 top open-source testing automation frameworks: How to choose"](https://techbeacon.com/6-top-open-source-testing-automation-frameworks-how-choose)) and then use these keywords to feed a trend engine.